# Sudo rm -rf does not remove a non-empty folder

Tags: ubuntu, mount, rm, ntfs

I have a mounted an external hard disk on `/media/pcmagas/Backup disk` containing a folder `dimitrios`. When I try to remove it with the following comand:

```
/media/pcmagas/Backup disk
sudo rm -rf ./dimitrios
```

I get this error:

```
rm: cannot remove './dimitrios/Kwdikas/Javascript/data_map/node_modules/random-bytes': Directory not empty
```

The mounted disk is ntfs, and I have mounted it into an Ubuntu GNU/Linux system.

When I run `ls -l ./dimitrios/Kwdikas/Javascript/data_map/node_modules/random-bytes` I get the following error:

```
ls: reading directory './dimitrios/Kwdikas/Javascript/data_map/node_modules/random-bytes': Input/output error
```

Comment: This could indicate filesystem corruption or a hardware issue. What does `dmesg` output after getting the I/O error?

Comment: Well I reformated the disk after backed up the wanted data.

Comment: You may want to run `badblocks` on the device since it's possible the disk might have bad sectors

Comment: Two questions — (a) which filesystem does “Backup disk” use? (b) are there any error messages from the kernel in `dmesg`, `/var/log/kern.log`, the systemd journal, etc.?

Comment: (a) Used NTFS (b) Havent Looked on it.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I'd guess you've hit a bug in the NTFS drivers for Linux. If this disk is just for backup from Linux, I'd strongly suggest using ext4, XFS, btrfs, etc. instead of NTFS. If you hadn't reformatted the disk, the next step would have been an fsck. Possibly from a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem you should do:

1. `rsync` any folder that you want to keep in the hard disk back to your computer's hard disk.
2. Then format it, you can use the `gparted` gui program to do so if you have an `XOrg` installed GNU/Linux system.
3. Move back the folders you kept.

I know its a bit hacky but for desktop use did the job in my case.